# Route table in MVC6 for web API not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code in Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                template: "api/{controller=Customers}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

… and declared the MVC dependency in project.json:

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": { },
        "aspnetcore50": { }
    },
    "bundleExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

I have the following controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        private List<Customer> _Customers = new List<Controllers.Customer>();

        public CustomersController()
        {
            _Customers.Add(new Customer() { ID = 1, Name = "Fred" });
            _Customers.Add(new Customer() { ID = 2, Name = "Bob" });
            _Customers.Add(new Customer() { ID = 3, Name = "Tim" });
        }

        public List<Customer> Get()
        {
            return _Customers;
        }

        public Customer Get(int ID)
        {
            Customer Customer = _Customers.Find(c => c.ID == ID);
            return Customer;
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

… but when I browse to /api/customers or /api/customers/1 I get a **404 Not Found**

Am is missing something? Is the route table for web API in MVC6 supported yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to port your Asp.Net Web API to MVC 6, you need to have [Web API Compatibility Shim](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim) . The default startup class code explains it

```
 // Uncomment the following line to add Web API servcies which makes it easier to port Web API 2 controllers.
 // You need to add Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim package to project.json
 // services.AddWebApiConventions();
```

By default it is switched off. Once enabled, you can configure web api route as

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

            // Uncomment the following line to add a route for porting Web API 2 controllers.
            // routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
        });
```

More details [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/migrating-asp-net-web-api-mvc-6-exploring-web-api-compatibility-shim/)

Answer (score 0):

I am bit late to answer this, but you need to put routing attribute

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

and remove the api from

```
template: "api/{controller=Customers}/{id?}");
```